# How to make a chrome extension which automatically logs in to my university login page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Everytime I have to access the net I first have to login to my university login page, how can I bypass that, I managed to write a chrome extension which automatically fills my username and password on the page but how can I make the browser click the login button for me? Any resources/ ideas/ suggested readings on this?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the click action on the button? something like $('button').click() on jquery

Answer (score 3):

Use Chrome's "save username and password" feature? OK, you don't want to do that.

Find the form and submit it.

If the form has an ID, then find it by ID:

```
var form = document.getElementById('id');
form.submit();
```

If not, perhaps there is only one form on the page, so you can find it as follows:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.submit();
```

If that doesn't work either, then you can use the username input to find its containing form. I'm assuming you have a reference to the username input, since you said you are able to fill in a value for it:

```
// Assume variable 'usernameInput' points to the username input element.
var form;
var p = usernameInput.parentNode;
while (p) {
    if (p.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'form') {
        form = p;
        break;
    }
}

if (form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

ETC.

You can also look for the Submit button and click it instead.

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
myButton.click();
```

I've had mixed success with clicking or submitting from a content script. Perhaps importing jQuery messes things up - I don't know for sure. So I found myself explicitly sending mouse events with this gem (adapt it for other event types as needed):

```
function clickElement(el) {
    el.css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
    el = $(el).get(0);
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, document, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.click()` method on the button element, or the `.submit()` method on the form element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "password box" addon.
You can download it of the Chrome web App Store.
The addon adds another button in the top right corner and if you click on it you can click on add new page or something like that and then you simply enter your username and password done!

What I then did is in the settings of chrome I added the login page as a page that automatically opens when I open chrome ,so then password box automatically enters username and passcode ,and you're logged in!
So after you set it all up you just need to open your browser and you're logged in!